# How to use my own classes as Core Data entities ? [Objective-C] [Xcode]

Tags: objective-c, oop, core-data, user-interface, xcode4

I'm quite surprised that I haven't been able to find the answer using Google so I hope someone will be able to help !

So here's the stuff : I have created several Objective-C classes. They work quite fine in console mode. Now I'm trying to create a user interface (because the console isn't that handy). I'd like to use all those classes I've made as entities in Core Data but I can't find a way to do so. If you know a way, please explain it to me and receive all my gratitude.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes must be subclasses of `NSManagedObject` to be compatible with Core Data and you'll need to build a data model to describe their contents.   More likely than not, you'll find it easier to start from near-scratch as you learn Core Data.

I would recommend [starting here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: Thank you. Long way to go before I can use Cocoa as I want to.